# Calculate raw moments in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate the first 4 raw moments of lists of data points, for example `my_list = [34.0, 35.0, 39.0, 43.0, 46.5, 48.5, 50.0, 51.5, 52.5]`.

I am aware of [scipy.stats.moment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html) but seems it only calculates central moments:

> scipy.stats.moment(a, moment=1, axis=0, nan_policy='propagate')
>
> Calculate the nth moment about the mean for a sample.
>
> A moment is a specific quantitative measure of the shape of a set of points. It is often used to calculate coefficients of skewness and kurtosis due to its close relationship with them.

I also notice there are [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html) functions for skewness or variance:

```
from scipy.stats import variation, skew
my_list = [34.0, 35.0, 39.0, 43.0, 46.5, 48.5, 50.0, 51.5, 52.5]

print(np.var(my_list))
print(variation(my_list))

print(skew(my_list))

>>> 44.0246913580247
>>> 0.14928998626833617
>>> -0.39001327934054053
```

but as you can see `numpy` and `scipy` return very different results.

What are the differences between these approaches and what's the most efficient way to find the first 4 raw moments(mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis)?

Comment: `scipy.stats.variation` returns the coefficient of variation, NOT the **variance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scipy.stats.describe()`:

```py
>>> x = [34.0, 35.0, 39.0, 43.0, 46.5, 48.5, 50.0, 51.5, 52.5]
>>> moments = scipy.stats.describe(x)
>>> moments.mean
44.44444444444444
>>> moments.variance
49.527777777777786
>>> moments.skewness
-0.39001327934054053
>>> moments.kurtosis
-1.3564638918570706
```